# Bot saying hi when added to guild

Tags: discord.js

I'm creating a bot using Discord.js and Node.js, and I want to detect when it's added to a guild.
How do I detect that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect it by **guildCreate** event

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate

```
client.on("guildCreate", async guild => {
    console.log("I added to a guild");
    console.log(guild);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `guildCreate` event as Alpha said.

```js
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel =>
    channel.type === 'GUILD_TEXT' && channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES')
  )
  channel.send("HI, Thanks for adding me!") // Sends a HI message to a random channel
})
```